# Sort an NSArray which contain custom objects

Tags: objective-c, ios, sorting, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSArray` which contain objects. my Objects are like this :

```
@interface Personne : NSObject{

    int _id;
    NSString *name;
}
```

I have a Web services which returns to me persons by name. for example; when I click in the search bar and I put "a", the server returns to me all the persons where her name contains "a", I put the result in an `NSArray`. Now I would like to sort my array and put the persons whose name begins with "a" in the beginning of my array and the others at the end. How can I do this?

Edit: For example I have the response of the server like this :

```
marakech  
arabie  
malakit  
arsenal  
astonvilla
```

I would like to sort like this :

```
arabie 
arsenal 
astonvilla 
malakit
```

Comment: This answer is exactly what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this method:

```
- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingComparator:(NSComparator)cmptr
```

which takes a comparator block, then you can put your sorting criteria in the block like this:

```
mySortedArray = [myArrat sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id a, id b) {
    //criteria;
    return [a compare:b];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd need an `NSMutableArray`, not `NSArray`. Also to sort use `sortUsingSelector:`

i.e. first you can write a method for your `Personne` class `- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(MyObj *)otherObj`, then you could can sort the mutable array with `sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)`

check this - [How to sort an NSMutableArray with custom objects in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it)